# In Visual Studio Express how do I update the "Deployment Provider url"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, publish

I am using Visual Studio Express 2013, and I am trying to publish a vb.net project.

Everything worked fine in my development environment, and I was able to use the "From a website" option to get the installed program to update.

I am ready to deploy to staging and changed all the references in the project from the dev environment to the staging environment. The install now fails as it is still trying to look at the dev domain to get the install files from (the dev domain can only be accessed on my dev machines)

- dev domain : www.mydomain-dev.com
- staging domain : www.mydomain-staging.com

This is the relevant info from the deails file

```
SOURCES
    Deployment url          : http://www.mydomain-staging.com/install/MyProject.application
                        Server      : nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
    Deployment Provider url     : http://www.mydomain-dev.com/install/MyProject.application
                        Server      : nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : MyProject.application, Version=1.0.0.12, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=37623d490c06d0e3, processorArchitecture=msil

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of http://www.mydomain-staging.com/install/MyProject.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Downloading http://www.mydomain-dev.com/install/Application Files/MyProject_1_0_0_12/MyProject.exe.manifest did not succeed.
        + The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
```

- I set the url in My Project -> Publish -> Updates... -> update location
- I set the url in the publish wizard
- I checked off Exclude deployment provider URL in My Project -> Publish -> Options... -? Manifests

I've also tried to "Clean Solution" and "Rebuild Solution"

How do I get rid of, or update, the "Deployment Provider url"?

edit:
I tried to change the publish wizard to option to "From a CD-ROM or DVD-ROM" to get the setup to work, then changed it back to my new url. Visual Studio is still remembering the old install url.

Answer (score 0):

In project properties find connection and change as you want to update the `url`.

A screenshot is given for your reference :

[image]

Comment: That is for ftp deployments, I chose "from a website" so there is no Connections option for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a great answer, but it is what has worked for me. I updated the deployment url again, from my staging url to my production url, and this time the installation works as expected.

So if anyone else has this issue, try to change the url again in the publish wizard.